# Count() where the item counted is a JOIN back to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm pretty sure I could have done a better job with the title of this post.  I wasn't sure how to shrink this question down into a working title...

I have two tables.  BillItems and SubItems.

SubItems:

```
SubItemId    ItemId    MasterItemId
-----------------------------------
    1          50          10
    2          50          11
    3          60          10
    4          60          12
    5          70          10
```

BillItems:

```
BillItemId    ItemId
---------------------
    1           10
    2           11
    3           50
    4           60
    5           70
```

Ok, so now, I need to know if BillItems contains any items that are chilren to more than one MasterItem, where the MasterItem is also inside of the BillItems table.  I know that sounds confusing, so I'll give an example:

Item 50 is a child item to both Item 10 and Item 11.  Item 10 and Item 11 are both in the BillItems table.  So, I need Item 50 to show up in the query.

Item 60 is a child to both Item 10 and Item 12.  Item 10 is in the BillItems table, but Item 12 is not.  So I don't want Item 60 to show up in the query.

Items 10 and 11 are not children in SubItems.  So I don't want it to show up in the query.

**EDIT:**

The desired output, with the above data, would be simply:

```
ItemId
------
  50
```

Comment: Maybe also show the desired output?

Comment: Good idea.  Done.

Comment: Both tables are related by ItemId, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Please confirm why 70 is not in the output?

Comment: 70 is not in the output because it only has one parent item.  I am looking for items who have more than one parent item, and where the parent items are in the BillItems table.

Comment: @Octavioccl -- I was loving your LINQ answer!!

Comment: Oh, I thought you are looking a sql query ;)

Comment: Well, I was, but only because I was pretty sure doing this in LINQ was going to be a PIA

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, as you can see is not so difficult, you have there three possible solutions ;)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston If you removed `11` from `BillItems` You would want only `70` returned, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT si.ItemId
FROM SubItems si
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 -- This EXISTS may be omitted if SubItems.ItemId has an enforced FOREIGN KEY reference to BillItems.ItemId
              FROM BillItems bi
              WHERE bi.ItemId = si.ItemId) 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM BillItems bi
              WHERE bi.ItemId = si.MasterItemId)
GROUP BY si.ItemId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT si.MasterItemId) > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var result=from b in context.BillItems
           let masters=context.SubItems.Where(s=>s.ItemId==b.ItemId).Select(s=>s.MasterItemId)
           where masters.All(e=>context.BillItems.Any(x=>x.ItemId==e))
           select b.ItemId;
```

I noticed later this is a sql question :), but @Casey wants to look how to this in Linq. Another solution (in case you use EF and nav properties) could be:

```
var result=context.BillItems.Where(b=>b.SubItems.All(s=>context.BillItems.Any(x=>x.ItemId==s.MasterItemId))
                            .Select(e=>e.ItemId);
```

Or also doing a group join:

```
var result=from b in context.BillItems
           join s in context.SubItems on b.ItemId equals s.ItemId into g
           where g.All(e=>context.BillItems.Any(x=>x.ItemId==e.MasterItemId))
           select b.ItemId;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a correlated sub-query to check if a masteritemid is present in the billitems table. For id's that aren't present you get a count of `0`. You can then `group by` the itemid and eliminate all such items where there is a missing item and when there are more than 1 items in the itemid group.

```
select itemid 
from (select itemid,(select count(*) from billitems where s.masteritemid=itemid) as present_or_not
      from subitems s
      ) x 
group by itemid 
having count(case when present_or_not=0 then 1 end)=0 and count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Hoping I understood your question correctly.

Please check below query

```
select a.ItemId ItemId_a
    --, count(distinct a.MasterItemId) , count(distinct b.ItemId)
    from SubItems a left join BillItems b
    on a.MasterItemId = b.ItemId
    group by a.ItemId
    having count(distinct a.MasterItemId)  = count(distinct b.ItemId)
    and count(distinct a.MasterItemId)>1
    ;
```

Comment: This will fail to return the ItemId for an item with more than two MasterItemId where there is also a MasterItemId not in BillItems. Example: `INSERT @SubItems VALUES
( 1, 50, 10 ),
( 2, 50, 11 ),
( 3, 60, 10 ),
( 4, 60, 12 ),
( 5, 70, 10 ),
( 6, 60, 80 );

INSERT @BillItems VALUES
( 1, 10 ),
( 2, 11 ),
( 3, 50 ),
( 4, 60 ),
( 5, 70 ),
( 6, 80 );`

Comment: Ok, thanks i am checking. please share expected output with input you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents:

```
/*
create table BillItems (BillItemId int, ItemId int)
create table Subitems (SubitemId int, ItemId int, MasterItemId int)

insert BillItems values (1,10)
insert BillItems values (2,11)
insert BillItems values (3,50)
insert BillItems values (4,60)
insert BillItems values (5,70)

insert Subitems values(1,50,10)
insert Subitems values(2,50,11)
insert Subitems values(3,60,10)
insert Subitems values(4,60,12)
insert Subitems values(5,70,10)
*/

;with x as (select itemId from subitems group by itemId having count(*) > 1)
, y as (select s.ItemId, b.BillItemId from x join subitems s on x.itemid = s.itemid left join Billitems b on s.MasterItemId = b.ItemID)
select distinct itemid from y
except 
select itemid from y where billitemid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT ItemId FROM TABLE1 t WHERE t.MasterId IN (SELECT ItemId FROM TABLE2)) as MasterInTable2
    EXCEPT
    (SELECT DISTINCT ItemId FROM TABLE1 t WHERE t.MasterId NOT IN (SELECT ItemId FROM TABLE2)) as
    MasterNotInTable2
```

Comment: sorry i didnt read the question carefully youd need to add the count part to check if it has more than 1 masterId

Comment: missing some parenthesis in this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #SubItems (
                            id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                            subItemID   INT,
                            ItemID      INT,
                            MasterItemID INT
                        )

INSERT INTO #SubItems
VALUES(1,50,10) 
INSERT INTO #SubItems
VALUES(2,50,11) 
INSERT INTO #SubItems
VALUES(3,60,10) 
INSERT INTO #SubItems
VALUES(4,60,12) 
INSERT INTO #SubItems
VALUES(5,70,10) 

CREATE TABLE #BillItems (
                            id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                            BillItemID  INT,
                            ItemID      INT
                        )

INSERT INTO #BillITems
VALUES(1,10)    
INSERT INTO #BillITems
VALUES(2,11)    
INSERT INTO #BillITems
VALUES(3,50)    
INSERT INTO #BillITems
VALUES(4,60)    
INSERT INTO #BillITems
VALUES(5,70)    


SELECT A.ItemID
FROM (
        SELECT bi.ItemID, COUNT(*) AS CountBill
        FROM #BillItems bi
        JOIN #SubItems si ON
            bi.ItemID = si.ItemID
        GROUP BY bi.ItemID
     ) A 
        JOIN #SubItems si ON
            A.ItemID = si.ItemID
WHERE si.MasterItemID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM #BillItems)
GROUP BY A.ItemID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1



DROP TABLE #SubItems
DROP TABLE #BillItems
```